# Number of Different Combination Possible?

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

You are given number of places as m and number of digits as n. You have to fill those m places in such a way that each digit appears at least one time.

For example

Given m as 4 and n as 3 so you have 4 places and 3 digits. Now For this total possible number of combinations are 36.

Lets take a simple example:

m=3 and n=2(a,b suppose) then possible combinations are

aba aab abb bab bba baa

Thus 6 combinations are possible only. Is there Any Formula for this because I am required to find the possible number of combinations?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming.

Comment: I can smell some DP here. Possibly some recursive function can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to the question

The answer is `n!S(m,n)`, where `S` is [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number).

For example, for `m=4, n=3`, `n!=6`, `S(4,3)=6`, so `n!S(m,n)=36` which is the expected answer.

### Why this formula?

Stirling numbers of the second kind `S(m,n)` count the number of ways to partition a set of `m` elements into `n` nonempty subsets. So for this question, `S(m,n)` count the number of ways to partition `m` places into `n` groups, each group corresponding to a digit. After the partition, we should designate one digit to each group, and there are `n!` ways to do this. Therefore, the answer is `n!S(m,n)`.

Comment: +1: thanks for a nice explanation - today I learned what a "Stirling numbers of the second kind" is!